# How do I not highlight (being highlighted using matchadd()) a pattern in comments in Vim

Tags: vim, verilog

For example, I want any character except space before or after a : to get highlighted. And for that I use:

`highlight OpSpace ctermbg=darkblue ctermfg=white guibg=#F59292`

`:au BufWinEnter *.v,*.sv let w:m1=matchadd('OpSpace', '[^ ][:]\|[:][^ ]', -1)`

This will highlight following:

reg [**3:0**] var;

The problem with it is that it highlights the comments also. Example being:

`// The Joker likes to:`

The **o:** part gets highlighted which I do not want (it is in a commented line, commented using //).

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

#### Use syntax highlighting with containment

Instead of using `matchadd()`, which is separate from the *syntax highlighting* mechanism, you could extend the default syntax rules for your filetype. In syntax highlighting, subordinate matches must be explictly *contained* in upper-level groups. To avoid matching in comments, just don't add a containment there. The downside here is that you're integrating with another syntax, and finding all the groups to add the containment may not be trivial.

#### Refine the regexp

If this is just about `//`-style comments, you can add a *negative lookbehind* (see `:help /\@<!`) to the pattern:

```
:au BufWinEnter *.v,*.sv let w:m1=matchadd('OpSpace', '\%(//.*\)\@<![^ ][:]\|[:][^ ]', -1)
```

This matches only when there's no preceding `//` in the line.